# Objective-C: Display an Array of Floats as an Image

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, nsimageview

In a Cocoa App I would like to display a 2d array of floats in an NSImageView.  To make the code as simple as possible, start off by converting the data from float to NSData:

```
// dataArray: an Nx by Ny array of floats
NSMutableData *nsdata = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:0];
long numPixels = Nx*Ny;
for (int i = 0; i < numPixels; i++) {
    [nsdata appendBytes:&dataArray[i] length:sizeof(float)];
}
```

and now try to display the data (the display is left blank):

```
[theNSImageView setImage:[[NSImage alloc] initWithData:nsdata]];
```

Is this the correct approach?  Is a CGContext needed first? I was hoping to accomplish this with NSData.

I have noted the earlier Stack posts: [32 bit data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494535/32-bit-component-images-with-cgimagecreate-are-actually-only-8-bit-component), [close but in reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026110/convert-nsdata-to-primitive-variable-with-ieee-754-or-twos-complement), [almost worked but no NSData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458770/nsimage-from-a-1d-pixel-array), [color image data here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225985/how-to-create-image-from-unsigned-char), but not much luck getting variations on these working.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I think you probably need to get in bed with CGContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it to work.  I had tried the NSBitmapImageRep before (thanks Tim) but the part I was missing was in properly converting my floating point data to a byte array. NSData doesn't do that and returns nil.  So the solution was not so much in needing to build up an NSImage float-by-float.  In fact, one can similarly build up a bitmapContext (using CGBitmapContextCreate (mentioned by HotLicks above)) and that works too, once the floating point data has been represented properly.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer to explain "properly converting my floating point data to a byte array". Showing the code that does that conversion would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `NSBitmapImageRep` to build up an `NSImage` float-by-float.

Interestingly, one of its initialisers has the longest method name in all of Cocoa:

```
- (id)initWithBitmapDataPlanes:(unsigned char **)planes 
                    pixelsWide:(NSInteger)width 
                    pixelsHigh:(NSInteger)height 
                 bitsPerSample:(NSInteger)bps 
               samplesPerPixel:(NSInteger)spp 
                      hasAlpha:(BOOL)alpha 
                      isPlanar:(BOOL)isPlanar 
                colorSpaceName:(NSString *)colorSpaceName 
                  bitmapFormat:(NSBitmapFormat)bitmapFormat 
                   bytesPerRow:(NSInteger)rowBytes 
                  bitsPerPixel:(NSInteger)
```

It's well documented at least. Once you've built it up by supplying float arrays in `planes` you can then get the `NSImage` to put in your view:

```
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:[bitmapImageRep CGImage] size:NSMakeSize(width,height)];
```

Or, slightly cleaner

```
NSImage *image = [[[NSImage alloc] init] autorelease];
[im addRepresentation:bitmapImageRep];
```

There is an initialiser which just uses an `NSData` container:

```
+ (id)imageRepWithData:(NSData *)bitmapData
```

although that depends on your `bitmapData` containing one of the correct bitmap formats.

Comment: Thanks Tim, as you suggest at the end, I think the problem may be that the "nsdata" defined above is not in one of the correct bitmap formats; how do I make the conversion from float to the "proper" bitmap format?